# How to create Persistence AR experience in Unity using ARKIT 2.0?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit

Hi I was trying the UnityARWorldMap example using ARKIT 2.0 in Unity.I ran on the Ipad,I placed the cube on a position with a touch and clicked save button.After Closing the app then I clicked load button and tracked the same place nothing came.Why the cube was not present at the same place.**What all things are required to save the cube and later load them to create persistence AR experience.**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.iOS;

public class WorldMapManager : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
UnityARCameraManager m_ARCameraManager;

ARWorldMap m_LoadedMap;

serializableARWorldMap serializedWorldMap;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    UnityARSessionNativeInterface.ARFrameUpdatedEvent += OnFrameUpdate;
}

ARTrackingStateReason m_LastReason;

void OnFrameUpdate(UnityARCamera arCamera)
{
    if (arCamera.trackingReason != m_LastReason)
    {
        Application.SetStackTraceLogType(LogType.Log, StackTraceLogType.None);
        Debug.LogFormat("worldTransform: {0}", arCamera.worldTransform.column3);
        Debug.LogFormat("trackingState: {0} {1}", arCamera.trackingState, arCamera.trackingReason);
        m_LastReason = arCamera.trackingReason;
    }
}

static UnityARSessionNativeInterface session
{
    get { return UnityARSessionNativeInterface.GetARSessionNativeInterface(); }
}

static string path
{
    get { return Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "myFirstWorldMap.worldmap"); }
}

void OnWorldMap(ARWorldMap worldMap)
{
    if (worldMap != null)
    {
        worldMap.Save(path);
        Debug.LogFormat("ARWorldMap saved to {0}", path);
    }
}

public void Save()
{
    session.GetCurrentWorldMapAsync(OnWorldMap);
}

public void Load()
{
    Debug.LogFormat("Loading ARWorldMap {0}", path);
    var worldMap = ARWorldMap.Load(path);
    if (worldMap != null)
    {
        m_LoadedMap = worldMap;
        Debug.LogFormat("Map loaded. Center: {0} Extent: {1}", worldMap.center, worldMap.extent);

        UnityARSessionNativeInterface.ARSessionShouldAttemptRelocalization = true;

        var config = m_ARCameraManager.sessionConfiguration;
        config.worldMap = worldMap;
        UnityARSessionRunOption runOption = UnityARSessionRunOption.ARSessionRunOptionRemoveExistingAnchors | UnityARSessionRunOption.ARSessionRunOptionResetTracking;

        Debug.Log("Restarting session with worldMap");
        session.RunWithConfigAndOptions(config, runOption);

    }
}


void OnWorldMapSerialized(ARWorldMap worldMap)
{
    if (worldMap != null)
    {
        //we have an operator that converts a ARWorldMap to a serializableARWorldMap
        serializedWorldMap = worldMap;
        Debug.Log ("ARWorldMap serialized to serializableARWorldMap");
    }
}


public void SaveSerialized()
{
    session.GetCurrentWorldMapAsync(OnWorldMapSerialized);
}

public void LoadSerialized()
{
    Debug.Log("Loading ARWorldMap from serialized data");
    //we have an operator that converts a serializableARWorldMap to a ARWorldMap
    ARWorldMap worldMap = serializedWorldMap;
    if (worldMap != null)
    {
        m_LoadedMap = worldMap;
        Debug.LogFormat("Map loaded. Center: {0} Extent: {1}", worldMap.center, worldMap.extent);

        UnityARSessionNativeInterface.ARSessionShouldAttemptRelocalization = true;

        var config = m_ARCameraManager.sessionConfiguration;
        config.worldMap = worldMap;
        UnityARSessionRunOption runOption = UnityARSessionRunOption.ARSessionRunOptionRemoveExistingAnchors | UnityARSessionRunOption.ARSessionRunOptionResetTracking;

        Debug.Log("Restarting session with worldMap");
        session.RunWithConfigAndOptions(config, runOption);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: "Alright, time to start up this program! Loading and deserializing the world! `ARWorldMap worldMap = serializedWorldMap;` Hmm...what's `serializedWorldMap`? Huh, it appears to be a class-level field that hasn't been set to a value yet. Welp, `worldMap` is null, so I guess I'm done!"

Comment: @Draco18s I have cube in my scene..how to save this cube and later load after closing the app.I know I have to save the position and rotation of the cube and later get it.What is the use of Arworld map?How to save it as a map?

Comment: I have never used ARWorld, but I can tell you right now that its not saving that's your problem, its loading. You're doing this: `ARWorldMap worldMap = serializedWorldMap;` which is functionally equivalent to `ARWorldMap worldMap = null;` which is most definitely not what you want.

Comment: @Draco18s I have given a statement to print in Update function of UnityArHitTestExample.cs .When I click Load() from the above given script,the update stops.How is that possible.Update will never stop ryt?

Comment: If update stops updating, that means you programmed an infinite loop and froze Unity.

Comment: @Draco18s..but  the app should freeze and quit but thats not happening..While testing I gave string  to print after Load is clicked Update stops.........https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55512273/why-update-function-not-working-in-unityarhittestexample-of-unityarworldmap-scen?noredirect=1#comment97733803_55512273